# Animating Irregular Sized Images

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-animation

Animating Irregular shaped Images

Is there a way to set the anchor point to the center of a group of images I am animating?

The images are not the same height or width, so when they animate, the animation is jumpy because the frames do not line up correctly. They would line up if they were anchored in the center. Is that possible?

I tired using the setAnchorPoint property, but my animation never shows up. If I use that.

The frame width and height is the largest size of the largerst animation frame. In the commented out code, the anchorpoint is half the size of the width and height of the frame.

```
CGRect frameABDG = CGRectMake(8, 78, 58, 113);
myAni = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frameABDG];
    //[myAni.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(29, 56.5)];
    myAni.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_1.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_2.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_3.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame_4.png"], nil];
    myAni.animationDuration = 1.0;
    myAni.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [myAni startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:myAni];
```

Comment: I dunno your other constraints but if I were trying to do this I would move all those images into a single transparent `UIView` with the same locations they had in the original parentView and then animate the new containerView.  Much easier.

Comment: What do you mean? Like a sprite-sheet? @Shizam

Comment: I mean create a UIView covering the area you want to display these images and place these images in that container view in the starting location you would like them to animate from.  Then perform the animation based on the midpoint of those images in that one view, now you're only animating one path not 4.